# Assigning current user_id as foreign value in a different table

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following tables users(id, name, email), articles(id, user_id, title, body). I can't seem to populate the user_id in articles table with the logged in user_id. This is my code.
//articles controller

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Article->create();
    $this->request->data['Article']['user_id'] = $user_id;
    if ($this->Article->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    }
    $users = $this->Article->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users'));
    }
```

The above method returns a null value for user_id in articles

I also tried retrieving from the view:

```
    echo $this->Form->hidden('user_id', arrray('value' => $userAuth['id']));
```

I get the following error
 syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: you wrote array with 3 'r'. check your code

Comment: also you never set the value of $user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('user_id', arrray('value' => $userAuth['id']));
```

Should be,

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('user_id', array('value' => $userAuth['id']));
```

Typo in arrray (3 times a R).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       $this->Article->create();
       if ($this->Article->save($this->request->data)) {
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article has been saved.'));
          return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
       } else {
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    else{
        $this->set('user_id', $userAuth['id']);
        $users = $this->Article->User->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }
}
```

in the view

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('Article.user_id', arrray('value' => $user_id));
```

But I don't know where you set `$userAuth`, be secure that you assign this variable before get its value